# Perforce plugin for Jenkins : can't get it to work

Tags: plugins, jenkins, perforce

I'm completely new to Jenkins and I never used a CI server before. I'm using perforce as a VCS, and I'd like to use it with jenkins.
I've read the wiki about Perforce Plugin and the how-to create a new job, but I still have some problems.
We will be 3 using Jenkins, so I don't want to use my IDs to login from Jenkins to Perforce. Icreated a new Perforce user for that "Jenkins". It means I haven't created any workspace etc.
1) I don't have any idea of what I'm supposed to write in the fields below "password"
Here is what I did for now, but I always have the red text. "Unable to check workspace against depot"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWngA.png

2) The project I need to build is coded in VB6. I know Jenkins can do it with Shells, but I didn't find any tutorial to do it and I find it far from intuitive. Do you know how to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The "workspace" field should be the name of your workspace.

Type 'p4 set' at the command line and look for the value of P4CLIENT. That's the workspace name that you should give to Jenkins.

Here's background information on the notion of a workspace in Perforce: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/02_config.html#1073386

Comment: Actually, it's wasn't in the task itself. The problem came from the P4 executable path. It's showed you have to set the path to the P4 directory (aka C:\perforce\) when you actually need the full path to the .exe (aka C:\perforce\p4.exe)